# Como recorrer columnas de una matriz en Python?

Tags: python, bucle-for, matriz

soy nuevo en la programación y tengo esta duda. Python. Como puedo recorrer una matriz con for? Como puedo recorrer las filas y luego las columnas? a=[[1,0,1], [1,0,0], [0,1,0]]

Quisiera recorrer primero las filas de esta matriz y luego las columnas. Lo he hecho creando una lista con las 3 filas y luego recorriéndola con for. lista=a[0]+a[1]+a[2]

lo mismo para las columnas. Creo una lista con todas las posiciones verticales, luego la recorro. col=a[0][0]+a[0][1]+a[0][2]+a[1][0]+a[1][1]+a[1][2]+a[2][0]+a[2][1]+a[2][2]

pero se que hay una manera mas eficaz y escribiendo menos código, con un for anidado...aunque no llego a comprender como funciona

Answer (score 1):

Una matriz en python no es más que una lista cuyos elementos son a su vez listas. Así, si tienes:

```
a=[[1,0,1], [1,0,0], [0,1,0]]
```

entonces `a[0]` será la primera lista `[1,0,1]`, y dentro de ella el elemento `[0]`, es decir `a[0][0]`, sería el primero de sus elementos (un `1` en este caso).

Como ves `a[i]` nos daría entonces la fila i-ésima (ya que cada sub-lista dentro de `a` se puede interpretar como una fila), pero no hay forma directa de conseguir una columna, porque la estructura de datos tiene los elementos de una columna repartidos por varias entradas.

No obstante, de forma general `a[i][j]` nos da el elemento que está en la fila `i`, columna `j`.

Así pues, podemos ir variando `i` entre 0 y 2 y también `j` entre 0 y 2 para ir creando todas las combinaciones posibles entre `i` y `j`. Esto se puede hacer con un bucle anidado:

```
for i in range(3):
  for j in range(3):
    print(i,j)
```

Si ejecutas el bucle anterior verás que salen (0,0), (0,1), (0,2) y después (1,0), (1,1), (1,2) y finalmente (2,0), (2,1) y (2,2). Por cada iteración del bucle exterior (en `i`) se ejecutará tres veces el bucle interior (en `j`) y así te salen todas las combinaciones posibles.

De ese modo puedes recorrer todos los elementos de la matriz, en este caso por el orden en que se verían al leerlos "por filas":

```
for i in range(3):
  for j in range(3):
    print(a[i][j])
```

De forma análoga, sin más que cambiar el orden de los bucles, puedes recorrer los elementos de `a` en el orden en que se verían leyendo "por columnas":

```
for j in range(3):
  for i in range(3):
    print(a[i][j])
```

Ahora ya puedes adaptar este código a lo que tú necesites, que no me ha quedado muy claro qué es (¿crear una lista con los elementos, en vez de imprimirlos?). Si tienes problemas al hacerlo, edita la pregunta para añadir más información.

### Ampliación para matrices de otros tamaños

Si la matriz no es de 3x3 puedes averiguar su tamaño en tiempo de ejecución con `len()`. Eso te da el número de elementos en una lista. Así por ejemplo `len(a)` te dirá cuántos elementos (sub-listas) tiene `a`, y por tanto cuántas filas.

Encontrar el número de columnas no es tan obvio, a menos que supongas una matriz cuadrada (en cuyo caso el número de columnas será simplemente igual al número de filas), o como mínimo rectangular, es decir, que todas las filas tengan el mismo número de elementos, en cuyo caso `len(a[0])` por ejemplo te diría cuántos elementos hay en la primera fila, y por tanto en todas las demás, y ese sería el número de columnas.

Comment: Gracias. es para un ejercicio de batalla naval, debo recorrer vertical y horizontalmente la matriz en busca de los 1. 1 representa un barco. Lo pude resolver con el codigo que habia puesto en la pregunta, pero no entendia como acceder a los elementos de una matriz de forma mas facil. Gracias

Comment: Ah, en ese caso imagino que la matriz no será de 3x3. He ampliado la respuesta para darte ideas de cómo abordar el caso más general.